# DP Vs Rendered pixel

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

actually I'm new to  iOS programming and Sprite Kit. I want to load an image as a background in my game[I used Sprite Kit].I load an image, but my image  cover some part of screen, not all of them.my question is, in Assets.xcasset,must put image in  image set which has 3 options. 1x,2x and 3x.
I want to simulate it in iPhone 5 which has Resolution[physical pixel ] 640x1136 and DP 320x568.the size of image that must be designed must be  Resolution size or DP?? below is my code.

import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene 
{
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

```
    let  exampleNode=SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "snake2")

    exampleNode.position=CGPoint(x:self.frame.size.width/2,   y:self.frame.size.height/2)


    self.addChild(exampleNode)

}
```

}

snake 2 is name of my image that was copied in project directory, also  scene.scaleMode=.AspectFill

Comment: your 1x Image would be DP size, your 2x image would be resolution size.  In reality, you should always be working in the DP size,  and let the 2x and 3x deternine the best image for your resolution

Comment: @Knight0fDragon, you mean  width and height of original image must be DP size ??[original image is image which was Designed ]

Comment: if you want the image to fill the iphone 5 screen, you make your 2x version the resolution screen (1136x640) and you make a scaled down version for your dp to be 568x320.  You then work in the 568x320 space in code, so if you were to call image.width, it will return 568, but in reality it is displaying the 2x image on your screen

Comment: one of the reasons this is designed this way is to reduce the use of division in code.  This was the basis for retina to begin with when introduced in iPhone 4. iPhone 3GS was 320x480 and iPhone 4 was 640x960. Your app can stay exactly the same, just provide a double res image to make it appear a lot nicer.

Comment: But I can't Load image in entire screen, what is problem?? Thanks for your answer

Comment: that I do not know, that was not your question